# How to wear Form Controls not move magnification in c #

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, screen

I put a picture in the background of the form, and applied Control s and Cshmgdilim the window to maxsize all Control s step aside even though everything is set to center. How can I lock the Control s on the form did not move at a magnification?
Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to make sure the control resizes along with the window?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking but I think you want to keep a control in the center of the form even when the form is resized. To do this at design time, just use the anchor property and choose all 4 sides

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908

If you want the control to resize to scale with the window, then use the docking property.

Comment: That's what I'm referring to! But how is it done??? I'd love if you give an example of the code. Thank you.

Comment: right click the control, click on properties. The properties tab will open then click the Anchor setting and it will show you a square with a line coming out of each side of the square. Click each line so it is colored in. Done. Look at the link, it has a walk through